# Use Dropwizard for AWS Redshift and Elasticache

Tags: jersey, amazon-redshift, dropwizard, jersey-client, amazon-elasticache

- I want to write a JDBC query api for amazon Redshift and Elasticache
  with Dropwizard and Jersey.
- I had google and review lots of blog
  about Dropwizard and Jersey. But until now I've no idea how to handle
  this.
- Is there any example for it?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use Dropwizard/Jersey combo ? We use Hibernate ORM to operate on RedShift from Java code.

Comment: Thanks @AritraGhoshDastidar
I want to build a Restful api server. so I think it's simply to use them. But also I can think about Hibernate ORM.

Comment: I have done this if you are still interested. Hibernate is not a restful api, it is an ORM, so saying why use Jersey and not hibernate does not make sense? One is to achieve a restful api, and the other is an ORM, you would never use one in place of the other, but you can use both.